# Why is this error happening with the imputation function in R?

Tags: r, imputation

I am trying to do an imputation based on this example: [impute example](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/impute.html)

```
data(airquality)
summary(airquality)

airq = airquality
ind = sample(nrow(airq), 10)
airq$Wind[ind] = NA
airq$Wind = cut(airq$Wind, c(0,8,16,24))
summary(airq)

imp = impute(airq, classes = list(integer = imputeMean(), factor = imputeMode()),
  dummy.classes = "integer")
```

which gives me a warning:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half + 0L:1L]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

However, when I try looking at the returned dataframe, I get:

```
> head(imp, 10)
Error in x[..., drop = drop] : incorrect number of dimensions

> head(imp$data, 10)
NULL
```

and `desc` gives:

```
> imp$desc
NULL
```

I had initially done the above using my actual data, and was getting these errors, so I tried the above example for a sanity check.

I've tried this in Windows both from RStudio and from the command line interface, all with same results on the example and my actual data. Also, tried using version 3.63 and 4.03, again with the same results.

I've also tried this on two fresh installs on Ubuntu, with the same results.

Interestingly, when I do `names` the dummy variable are not there:

```
> names(imp)
[1] "Ozone"   "Solar.R" "Wind"    "Temp"    "Month"   "Day"
```

`str(imp)` gives:

```
> str(imp)
Classes ‘impute’ and 'data.frame':      153 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Ozone  : num  41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
 $ Solar.R: num  190 118 149 313 NA NA 299 99 19 194 ...
 $ Wind   : Factor w/ 3 levels "(0,8]","(8,16]",..: 1 1 2 NA 2 2 2 2 3 2 ...
 $ Temp   : int  67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
 $ Month  : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Day    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "imputed")= int [1:54] 5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

and looking at one of the columns on which imputation should have taken place:

```
> head(imp$Solar.R)
[1] 190 118 149 313  NA  NA
```

(my actual data replaced `NA` with all 0's, even though it should have been the column mean)

UPDATE: I tested this just now on my local machine running MacOS and getting the exact same error.

Comment: I ran your code and can't reproduce your example, the function works as intended. Have you tried the usual? Restarting R, reinstalling packages and dependencies, etc.?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either. The vignette calls for `head(imp$data, 10)`. Your code `head(imp, 10)` prints 10 parts of the list, but there are only 2 parts so it prints everything. Both `mlr` (the old version) and `mlr3` (the new version) give the same results.

Comment: Thanks both for confirming that this is an environment issue. I did just restart and reinstall and am still having the same problem. This is on a windows machine -- I'm going to try installing this on Ubuntu now.

Comment: incidentally, `head(imp$data, 10)` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Interestingly, a fresh install of R on Ubuntu is producing the same error! Weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using whichever version of `impute` was in the `Hmisc` library. Using `mlr` did the trick.

```
> imp$desc
Imputation description
Target: 
Features: 6; Imputed: 6
impute.new.levels: TRUE
recode.factor.levels: TRUE
dummy.type: factor
```